# How do I get the scale and rotate option to fit in the middle of my object?

Tags: transforms, selection-tools

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Alright so my character usually has the rotate/scale tool inside of them but im not sure what i did and its stuck outside now. In picture 1 is where my character got spawned in but when i try to move the green arrow it doesn't move forward with my character. In picture 2 i moved my character forward but the tool still stayed in the middle. How do I fix this? c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have switched the pivot point to *3D Cursor*, which is the red/white circle in the center of the world. You can change it in the menu right next to "Global". The default setting is *Median Point*, in *Object Mode* with only one object selected this would mean you rotate and scale around the object's origin. With several objects selected this rotates/scales them around their mutual center.

I cannot see the origin in the screenshot, so if that's somewhere off and *Median Point* doesn't work for you, you should right-click on the object and choose *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry*.

[image: pivot point]

[image: origin]

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set the pivot point to bounding box:

[image]

Comment: In the second screenshot you see that the object's location is almost 32 m in +Y direction and 1.5 m in +Z, I guess that's why there is no origin visible. Although displaying the bounding box might show it around the mesh, using _Bounding Box Center_ in _Object Mode_ will result in rotating around the origin, which is even further off than the _3D Cursor_ and thus not work as Lola expected.